# Meaning of delivering project commitment

Tags: meaning

I recently came over a couple of job offers and curriculums where someone delivers project commitment.

Intuitively, I would say this means that someone "commits" to the project by ensuring deadlines are met, milestones achieved, etc. I would appreciate if you could correct me / provide a more precise definition.

Comment: Could you provide more context, like the whole paragraph containing the phrase? My guess is it means delivering what they committed to, but it's hard to be sure.